Ratchet/Cliquet Options vs Vanilla Option
I am trying to value a call option with ratchet strike features using Monte Carlo Simulation. Specifically, the option has an initial strike of 10 and will adjust down its strike to 8 if stock below 8 on the first anniversary date. Say the option has a time to maturity of 3 years and stock here is 11.5 and pays no dividend, would this ratchet/cliquet call option has more value than the vanilla call option intuitively? Because if stock went lower, it has a chance to reset strike and become ATM/ITM? Thanks!

Your intuitive argument is correct.
